# Listeners on EditText in RecyclerView start firing infinitely

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, textwatcher, onfocuschangelistener

I have a rather strange issue when using either `OnFocusChangeListener` or `TextWatcher` in my `RecyclerViewAdapter`. I have a non-static list of input fields in the `RecyclerView`, and I want to listen for changes basically as soon as the user is done typing. **When tapping on an input, the listeners or watchers begin firing infinitely about 10 times a second.** The adapter is a `RealmRecyclerViewAdapter` but I don't think that is causing the issue. 
I have tried setting the listeners in the `ViewHolder` constructor and in `onBindViewHolder`. Here is my `FocusChangeListener`

```
    private class BodyFocusChangeListener implements OnFocusChangeListener {
    private int position;
    private boolean isFocused;

    public void updatePosition(int position) {
        this.position = position;
    }

    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean hasFocus) {
            String noteId = getItem(position).getId();
            updateNote(noteId, ((EditText) view).getText().toString());
    }
}
```

and in `onBindViewHolder`

```
holder.titleFocusChangeListener.updatePosition(holder.getAdapterPosition());
```

so that my listener knows which element is which.

Comment: implement both listeners inside custom `ViewHolder`

Comment: If you could expand that into an answer...

Comment: what to expand? just call `setOnFocusChangeListener(this)` / `addTextChangedListener(this)` inside your custom `ViewHolder` constructor